# How can I get conditional protocol conformance with a protocol's parent?

Tags: swift

I have the following setup:

```
protocol Resource : Codable {}

class A<T> {}

extension A where T : Codable {
    func doThingWithCodable() {}
}

let a = A<Resource>()

a.doThingWithCodable()
//Error: Protocol type 'Resource' cannot conform to Codable because
//only concrete types can conform to protocols.
```

I understand the error message, and I've read numerous Q&A's on generics, protocols and conditional conformance. I have a number of classes that conform to the `Resource` protocol, so it'd be really convenient if there was a way to let `A<Resource>` know that it will always be working with concrete types that conform to `Codable`, so I could still have one instance of `A<Resource>`, and that instance could have access to its conditional `Codable` methods. I did think about just making an instance like `A<Codable>`, but I need some of the properties that are inside the `Resource` protocol too.

Is there a swifty way to resolve this besides creating a new instance of `A` for each concrete type that conforms to `Resource`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question as posed, "How can I get conditional protocol conformance with a protocol's parent?" is meaningless, because a protocol *always* conforms with its parent; there is no "conditional" about it.

As for your actual code, the problem is the phrase `A<Resource>`. Saying `A<Resource>` is not a correct resolution of A's T. You need to resolve T as a class, struct, or enum — not as a protocol.

For example, if you have a class B that conforms to Resource, you can declare

```
let a = A<B>()
```

and all is well.

> if there was a way to let `A<Resource>` know that it will always be working with concrete types that conform to `Codable`

Well, as I said, your code compiles fine as soon as A is working with a concrete type that *does* conform to `Codable`. So if that's what A will always be working with, there's nothing more to do. You could of course tell A that its T will always conform to Resource (which by definition will always conform to Codable):

```
class A<T:Resource> {}
```

Comment: Ok. So in short, the answer to my final question is no, correct? Setting things up as you described requires declaring an instance of `A` for each concrete type that conforms to `Resource`.

Comment: Well that’s what a generic is. Each time you use it you must resolve it. Specifically. Maybe a generic was never what you wanted? But you did not explain what you wanted.

Comment: Maybe you just want A to take a Resource as a _parameter_ and not be a generic at all?

Comment: I was trying to use a minimal reproducible example, sorry if I left out some detail. I'm working with a subclass of `NSCache`. Thank you.

Comment: Yes well this is probably an xy question. I suggest asking a whole new question.

Comment: Asked a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57812816/how-can-i-get-this-subclass-of-nscache-to-work-with-a-protocol)

Answer (score 0):

Just think about this:

```
let a = A<Resource>()
```

This statement is trying to create an instance of class `A` and assigning it to `a`. The compiler doesn't know what this resource exactly is and how much memory it should allocate and what optimization it should run; because here `Resource` can be anything.

To resolve that, you need to provide little more information i.e. which you are already aware of.

```
struct CoffeeResouce: Resource {
    let isWarm: Bool
}
```

Now when you write this:

```
let a: A<CoffeeResource> = A()
```

The compiler is well about the type and it's memory requirements. This is one way of resolving.

Or permanently tell the class that `T` conform to the protocol by declaring the class.

```
class A<T: Resource> {}
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw your answer when I finished posting mine. I just kept it as it differs in the description and may add a little value. What do you think:  should I keep it or delete it?